# Can I install both ready for sale and beta test flight versions?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

In iTunes Connect, I have a Ready for sale version, available for public download. Also, I have a beta versión with some improvements on design, etc.

May I have installed both, production and beta versions, at the same time on one device to test the beta and compare it with the production released?

Comment: I don't think so. You may have multiple applications if bundle identifier is different (com.xxx.xxx). If you install an application over another with the same bundle id it will override it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: Absolutely not. Before you asking a question. Please research or try at least once. I think it is not hard to install an application on you iphone

Comment: This is a complex area and the apple docs don't really cover what you ask from what I can see. The following article does offer a solution which focuses on using build settings to let you test the iTunes release and the new at the same time on the same device.: http://blog.xebia.com/2015/01/30/run-your-ios-app-without-overwriting-the-app-store-version/.

Comment: @trojanfoe maybe this is not about programming, but is about a developer portal. On the other hand, if it's about the bundle id, I think this is not an off-topic question.

Comment: @VũTuấnAnh I swear I've searched for several minutes trying to find that concrete question, with any success on my search.

Comment: @abrahamnavas This site is for programming questions, not all subjects that might interest programmers.

Comment: @trojanfoe there are so many other questions about iTunes Connect, not mainly related with any code issue. But it doesn't matter, I will delete the question. Do you know a better forum to post that question looking for an answer? Thanks and apologies for the inconveniences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, I don't think that's possible.
The app id (com.company.appID) must be unique, iOS won't let you install two applications with the same app id next to each other.

You could have a second App in iTunesConnect for tests, and send the same application with the only change being in the app id.